# How can LyX create a pdf file that's suitable for Amazon Createspace publishing?

Tags: pdftex, lyx, pdf

LyX by default creates documents in pdf file format version 1.5

Amazon Createspace says that it supports pdf submissions in pdf file format version 1.4 and below. They don't say they support this output of version 1.5 or above.

What adjustments need to be made in LyX or to PdfLaTeX to create files in a pdf file format version that Amazon Createspace supports?

Comment: The duplicate tells you to set `\pdfminorversion=4`.  If you want this reopened you should explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - I only edited the posting to clarify its objective. I agree with you that the posting should closed unless the OP can demonstrate that the solution proposed in the earlier posting does not work for him/her.

Comment: I wrote the new question and it turns out the original solution worked for me. However, the other's question makes no sense in light of Createspace users who read their quidelines telling them they "support PDF Version 1.4 and below" The "Version 4" above isn't a file format version, but rather the Adobe Acrobat application version, which me and others don't use.  The other's question needs major editing, because there is NO pdf version 4 or 5 in existence.  It's only up to PDF Version 1.7, and Createspace supports versions 1.4 and below.  The naming conventions are WRONG in the other's.